# Editing line in config file with Sed

Tags: bash, sed

I'm sure this is really simple, but I have been having some issues.

I'm trying to create a bash script to update a line in a config file based on a argument passed to it.

The config file looks like this:

```
//globalConfig.php
'General' => array(
    'env_name' => 'Global',             
    'project_name' => 'ProjectName',    
    'version' => 'x.x.x'                
),
```

And I am trying to create a script that changes the 'version' value.  The script I have ended up with, which doesn't work is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sed -i "s/^\'version\'.*/\'version\' => \'$1\'/" globalConfig.php
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: TFW a config file is actually code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try (using *GNU* `sed`, as implied by your question):

```
sed -i -r "s/^(\s*'version'\s*=>).*/\1 '$1'/" globalConfig.php
```

- `-r` enables support for *extended* regular expressions, which allows for definition of capture group `(\s*'version'\s*=>)` using the expected modern syntax.

  - `\s*` matches any (potentially empty) run of whitespace, making for more flexible matching.
- `\1` in the replacement operand refers to what the first (and only) capture group captured, which makes it unnecessary to repeat the `'version' =>` part.
- Note that `$1` is expanded by the *shell*, *up front*, to supply the replacement value, which assumes that the value of `$1` doesn't break the script that `sed` sees as a result; specifically, `$1` must not contain (unescaped) `/` and `\` instances.

---

As for what you tried:

- Inside `"..."` (a double-quoted *shell* string), `'` chars. can be used as-is - do not `\`-escape them.
- Since `^` matches the start of the line, `'version'` won't be matched immediately after, because there is intervening whitespace in your sample input.

Comment: Thanks for your help, and a really clear explanation.